# No route matches [POST] "/user_steps/profile"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

trying to create a 2 step wizard using the Wicked gem. 
Each step goes to different models. First to the user model, second to the the profiles. User has many profiles.

I'm able to succesfully complete first step. The 'personal' where I ask them to add their email. However when I try to create the 2nd step I get:

```
No route matches [POST] "/user_steps/profile"
```

what I want to do is create a current_user.profiles.new.

Here is my controller code:

```
class UserStepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :personal, :profile

    def show
      @user = current_user
      case step
      when :profile
        @profile = current_user.profiles.new
      end 
      render_wizard
    end

    def update
      @user = current_user
      case step
        when :personal
          @user.update_attributes(personal_params)
        when :profile
          @profile = current_user.profiles.new(profile_params)
          if @profile.save
            redirect_to root_url
          else
            redirect_to :back
          end
      end 
      render_wizard @user
    end

    private

    def personal_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email)
    end

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:followers)
    end
end
```

the profile form is simple and looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @profile, url: wizard_path do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :followers %>

  <%= f.button %>
<% end %>
```